# How to tell if an anonymous query contains order by?

Tags: oracle11g, sql-order-by

My system needs to validate if an oracle query contains order by. I thought I would do with regex but I wanted to know if oracle does not have a ready solution.

I tried to execute the with oracle explain plan but in some queries the order by does not appear in the plan.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex:

```
.*order by.*
```

Some queries that don't have an `order by`, such as `union`, still internally perform sorts, so you can't tell by looking explain plan if an order by has been used.

Comment: It will be difficult to secure with regex. The ideal would be to use some oracle function.